# The grade won't display

Tags: c++

I've been working on this all day, and still no success. Just error after error. I'm trying to get grade to display correctly, but nothings working.

(Note grade it grde)

This is my header.

```
//Ashton Dreiling
//Essay class header
#ifndef ESSAY_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define ESSAY_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class EssayClass
{

//private fields to hold data
private:
    double Grammar;
    double Spelling;
    double CL;
    double Content;
    double score;
    string grade=" ";
//public methods for outside code
public:
    EssayClass(double G, double S, double corlen, double content, double Score, string Grade)
    {
        Grammar = G;
        Spelling = S;
        CL = corlen;
        Content = content;
        score =Score;
        grade=Grade;
    }//end EssayClass constructor

    //method to add score
    void addScore()
    {
        score = Grammar + Spelling + CL + Content;
    }// end add score

    //method to show final grade
    void findGrade()
    {
    if (score>=95)
            grade= "A";
        else if (score>=79)
            grade= "B";
        else if (score >=50)
            grade= "C";
        else if (score<=50)
            grade= "F";

    }//end findGrade

    double getGrammar()
    {
        return Grammar;
    }//end getGrammar

    double getSpelling()
    {
        return Spelling;
    }//end getSpelling

    double getCL()
    {
        return CL;
    }//end getCL

    double getContent()
    {
        return Content;
    }//end getContent

    double getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }//end getScore

    string getGrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }//end getGrade
};//end class
#endif // ESSAY_CLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

This is my main.

```
 // Ashton Dreiling
//Essay exercise program
#include <iostream>
#include "Essay class.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int NUM_FOR_CAL1=0;
using namespace std;

void userInput(double &grammar, double &spelling, double &CL, double &content);

int main ()
{
    //some variables
    double grmmr;
    double splling;
    double correctlength;
    double con;
    string grde;



    userInput(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con);

    //displaying the scores that were inputed
    cout << "The recorded scores are:" << endl;
    cout << "Grammar: " << grmmr << endl;
    cout << "Spelling: " << splling << endl;
    cout << "Correct Length: " << correctlength << endl;
    cout << "Content: " << con << endl;

    EssayClass essayObject(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con, grde);
    //calling member functions with essay object
    userInput(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con);

    essayObject.addScore();
    essayObject.findGrade();
    essayObject.getGrade();
    string grde=essayObject.getGrade();


    //final grade
    cout << "The grade for this essay is: " << grde << endl;


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}//end main

void userInput(double &grmmr, double &splling, double &correctlenght, double &con)
{

    //input from user to enter points
    cout << "Enter the points for an essay." << endl;
    cout << "Grammar (must be 30 or less points)." << endl;
    cin >> grmmr;
    while (grmmr>30 || grmmr<NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Grammar must be 30 or less points." << endl;
        cin >>grmmr;
    }//end while loop
    cout << "Spelling (must be 20 or less points)." << endl;
    cin >> splling;
    while(splling>20 || splling<NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Spelling must be 20 or less points." << endl;
        cin>>splling;
    }//end while loop
    cout << "Correct length (must be 20 or less points)." << endl;
    cin>>correctlenght;
    while(correctlenght>20 || correctlenght<NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Correct length must be 20 or less points." << endl;
        cin >> correctlenght;
    }//end while loop
    cout << "Correct content (must be 30 or less points)." << endl;
    cin>>con;
    while(con>30 || con<NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Content must be 30 or less points." << endl;
        cin >> con;
    }//end while loop
}// end user input
```

Comment: Have you started the debugger and stepped through your code to see that the values are being set as expected? There's a few eye-brow raisers that I see right off the bat, but not directly (or at least noticeably) that stick out.

Comment: I have, but I've gotten nothing. I've even reinstalled codeblocks, but still nothing. I'm a beginner to code and this is the first program involving classes I've done, so I'm not sure what they eyebrow raises are. @M4rc

Comment: Note: File names with spaces cause 100% more problems than file names without them. In reference to `"Essay class.h"`.

Comment: Most noticeably is that `grde` is used before it is created; which can't allow it to compile in my mind..

Comment: When I fix the call to userInput() in main, removing the `grde` parameter, I am able to compile, run. if I enter full points for everything I get the expected 'A'. **Edit**: As well as declare `std::string grde` below `double scr;`

Comment: Might be intentional, but `addScore` doesn't use its argument.

Comment: @M4rc

I believe I did what you said, but it's saying I have two errors. 
http://prntscr.com/c0ih2g

Most likely did something wrong.

Comment: @Torbjörn
I deleted scr, but now I have three errors. I don't know what's happening. 

http://prntscr.com/c0ihoa

I'm going to edit my code to show you guys what I have.

Comment: @PeterFriedman -- So you wrote all of this code in one sitting without compiling a step at a time, and you're only now starting to compile your code?  If not, go back to when the code compiled successfully and see what you added that caused the error.

Comment: @PeterFriedman you changed `grde` to be of type `double` instead of type `string`. That's the first i see. The second one is that you say `string grde =  essayObject.getGrade();` which is an error, because you have defined `grde` to be of type `double` earlier on in your main function, and then are redefining it to a different type later.

Comment: No, I compiled step by step, but I couldn't fix the one last error. Now I have a few, so I'm trying to fix it. 

@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: It says no matching function for addscore, redeclaration of std::string grde, and I have a third error but it's not saying what it is (My IDE has always been working partially). I changed it to string. 

@M4rc

Comment: Be sure to update the question with the latest code change. And are you doing "clean" and then "rebuild all", or the codeblocks equivalent? Sometimes stale object files can be a pain..

Comment: Never even heard of that. Let me give it a go and show you the errors I have then. Thanks for being patient. This has been a pain and no one has been able to help haha.

@M4rc

Comment: `essayObject.addScore();` `essayObject.findGrade();` `essayObject.getGrade();` ` **string grde** =essayObject.getGrade();` <------- is still the error I see with your code.

Comment: I declared it as a string as up.

Did that not fix it? 

@M4rc

Comment: Does it compile? Or you receive error messages during compilation?

Comment: Not yet 

http://prntscr.com/c0iqdg @user31264

Comment: You should explain that your code does not compile, and include the link to prntscr.com/c0iqdg **in your original message**.

Comment: @PeterFriedman current things I see: 1) `essayObject.getGrade();` is still returning to `string grde` despite `grde` being declared a double in the beginning of your `main`. 2) you're giving `userInput` 5 parameters, but declared it as 4.

Comment: The code shown can't compile: you pass the wrong number of arguments to the EssayClass constructor: you don't pass a score to it (so you should either pass 0 or remove the parameter from the constructor)

Comment: I apologize. Thank you for your note. I will. 

@user31264

Comment: @kfsone

I thought I don't use score? Well, the guy before said I don't use score as an argument in addScore. So, I assumed--which my assumption may be wrong--that I don't need to pass score to the constructor and therefore don't need it in my essay object. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Tell me if I'm reading correctly, but you're saying it's still showing up for you as double and saying there are five parameters in userInput? Unless I'm counting wrong, it doesn't show that for me with the updated code. It shows I declared it as a string and have four parameters. @M4rc

Comment: @peterfriedman you can't just not provide a value for a function parameter because its not used. I suggest you re-review what you've learned about defining and using function argument lists.

Comment: `EssayClass(double G, double S, double corlen, double content, double Score, string Grade)`. You have to provide values for each of those. And remember, the arguments are positional, not name based

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me..

```
 class EssayClass{

     //private fields to hold data
     private:
     //Member names are best(In my opinion) given as: m_typeName. IE:double m_dblGrammar;
          double Grammar;
          double Spelling;
          double CL;
          double Content;
          double score;
          string grade;
     //public methods for outside code
     public:
          EssayClass(double G, double S, double corlen, double content, double Score, string &Grade){
         Grammar = G;
         Spelling = S;
         CL = corlen;
         Content = content;
         score = Score;
         //Set this here instead of in the private section as this is not a static variable.
         grade= "";
     }//end EssayClass constructor

//method to add score
//NOTE: You do not use the parameter; thus was omitted.
     void addScore(){
         score = Grammar + Spelling + CL + Content;
     }// end add score

//method to show final grade
     void findGrade(){
          //Another thing I'm fond of, which helps prevent typo's
         //Is to have your constant be a left hand compare. For example
        //if(5 == foo). Help you prevent from accidental if(foo = 5)'s
         if (score >= 95)
              grade = "A";
         else if (score >= 79)
              grade = "B";
         else if (score >= 50)
              grade = "C";
         else //this should probably be just "else"
              grade = "F";

     }//end findGrade

     double getGrammar(){
         return Grammar;
     }//end getGrammar

     double getSpelling(){
         return Spelling;
     }//end getSpelling

     double getCL(){
         return CL;
     }
      double getContent(){
              return Content;
          }//end getContent
      double getScore(){
             return score;
         }//end getScore

      string &getGrade(){
        return grade;
    }//end getGrade
};//end class
```

And:

```
void userInput(double &grammar, double &spelling, double &CL, double &content);

int main ()
{
    //some variables, good habit is to set these to 0, although that's probably just 'C' Mentality that I haven't gotten rid of
    double grmmr = 0.0;
    double splling = 0.0;
    double correctlength = 0.0;
    double con = 0.0;
    double scr = 0.0;
    std::string grde = "";

    //Note: 4 parameters in declaration, 4 in useage.
    userInput(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con);

    //displaying the scores that were inputed
    cout << "The recorded scores are:" << endl;
    cout << "Grammar: " << grmmr << endl;
    cout << "Spelling: " << splling << endl;
    cout << "Correct Length: " << correctlength << endl;
    cout << "Content: " << con << endl;

    EssayClass essayObject(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con, scr, grde);
    //calling member functions with essay object
    userInput(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con);

    essayObject.addScore();
    essayObject.findGrade();
    essayObject.getGrade();
    //NOTE: There is no string grde here, as I declared it above.
    grde = essayObject.getGrade();


    //final grade
    cout << "The grade for this essay is: " << grde << endl;

    //generally bad practice to use system calls -- however for homework it has it's purpose.
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}//end main

void userInput(double &grmmr, double &splling, double &correctlenght, double &con)
{

    //input from user to enter points
    cout << "Enter the points for an essay." << endl;
    cout << "Grammar (must be 30 or less points)." << endl;
    cin >> grmmr;
    while (grmmr > 30 || grmmr < NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Grammar must be 30 or less points." << endl;
        cin >> grmmr;
    }//end while loop
    cout << "Spelling (must be 20 or less points)." << endl;
    cin >> splling;
    while(splling > 20 || splling < NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Spelling must be 20 or less points." << endl;
        cin>> splling;
    }//end while loop
    cout << "Correct length (must be 20 or less points)." << endl;
    cin>> correctlenght;
    while(correctlenght > 20 || correctlenght < NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Correct length must be 20 or less points." << endl;
        cin >> correctlenght;
    }//end while loop
    cout << "Correct content (must be 30 or less points)." << endl;
    cin>> con;
    while( con > 30 || con < NUM_FOR_CAL1)
    {
        cout << "Content must be 30 or less points." << endl;
        cin >> con;
    }//end while loop
}// end user input**
```

Comment: After looking at this for a long time, I now understand haha.

Comment: I compiled it on code blocks though and it didn't work 
@M4rc  http://prntscr.com/c0jx3g

Comment: I get all these http://prntscr.com/c0jyc4

Comment: @PeterFriedman That is because I only pasted the relevant stuff. Which was the class definition and what not.  I omitted the `using namespace std;` part, as well as headers and your constant value. Those have to be replaced in.

Comment: Oh, well it helped a lot! I got it working. : ) @M4rc

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

```
string grade=" ";
```

You cannot do this in C++.  You cannot initialize members like this. Fix it!

```
EssayClass(double G, double S, double corlen, double content, double Score, string Grade)
```

So EssayClass constructor takes 5 doubles and one string. OK.

```
EssayClass essayObject(grmmr, splling, correctlength, con, scr, grde);
```

You call the EssayClass constructor with 4 doubles, one "scr" (there is no such variable), and one double.  This is not what it accepts. Fix it!

On a side note, don't start variables with capital letter!  This is considered a poor style.  Capital letters are for macros, class names and other type names, and sometimes for functions (including member functions).

On another side note, all your getSomething functions should be constant, and getGrade() should return `const string&`, not `string`.  Similarly, your constructor should receive `const string&`, not `string`.  Formally it is not an error, but such passing of parameters make inefficient code.

You should always make a space before and after "=", otherwise your code will be hard to read.

You have more problems with your code, but first, fix these.

Comment: Well, firstly my professor doesn't want me to use constants for this one. 

As for the rest, let me attempt to fix them. : )

Comment: Okay, don't use constants if your teacher doesn't want it.

Comment: When you say my constructor should receive &string, I'm a bit confused what you mean. (Sorry some wording for me just sets me off) 

Also thanks for the advice! Reduced my errors to one. 

@user31264

Comment: He means calling it with regular `string` passes it as a copy, instead of passing it as a reference (`string &`) which passes the actual identity.

Comment: So I should put &grde? @M4rc

Comment: @user31264 `std::string member = "";` is perfectly legal C++11. Your remarks about getters are somewhat overly stressed, certainly, not significant to his issues.

Comment: @PeterFriedman Yes. But it's important that you understand _why_ you do these things, especially with non POD objects. A teacher will likely ask you later on; and if not, you'll still be ahead of the curve for having that knowledge.

Comment: @user31264 see 9.2.8 of the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem

Comment: @kfstone, ok, in c++11 they added this feature.  Getters need to be constant, it is a good style.  It is also a terrible idea to return string (or anything else except primitive types, pointers, and some other things) not by reference, as it destroys the efficiency.

Comment: @PeterFriedman - usr `string&` instead of `string`.

Comment: @M4rc When I did &grde in main it gave me errors. When I did it in class so &Grade it compiled fine. Are you sure I do it in main? 

Also, alright. Explain to me.

Comment: M4rc is right. If you don't know what is passing parameters by reference, or returning by reference, don't use references yet.

Comment: @M4rc - you are right.

Comment: You don't want to do it in a variable declaration (not in `string &variable`) in main. You want to use it in function returns ( `string &getString()` ) or in parameters ( `int somefunct(string &val)` ). Copying for a container can be more expensive than passing the actual object itself. Likewise, sometimes can result in unexpected behavior. Or at least, did for me once on an arm cpu.

Comment: I know what it is. It's just a bit trickier for me with classes is all. : ) 

  string getGrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }//end getGrade  This is the return for grade. I assume I put &grade in the parameters in the class. That's what I'm understanding. 

@M4rc

Comment: @PeterFriedman in the constructor, yes. Review my answer to see what I mean if you're not sure.

Comment: @PeterFriedman - the rule of thumb is: any parameter which is not a basic type, or pointer, or enum, is passed by reference; getters return anything which is not a basic type, or pointer, or enum, by reference.  The copy constructor must always take its parameter by reference, otherwise it gets into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on the side:

1. Avoid "using namespace std;" in the header file, because all files including it will inherit this.
2. if grade always will be one character, you could use char instead
3. if grade is calculated, you don't need to pass it in the constructor, you can calculate it in the constructor instead.